# Unique Logic/Code Breaking Problem

Tags: logic, recreational-mathematics, coding-theory

I have been tasked with finding the answer to this problem which includes a 10x10 box filled with letters. (See below) I must find what four letters are missing and why? I have tried to find the code elsewhere, but unable to, I have used this as my last resort. Thanks

[image: The box that shows the letters and how they are organized.]

Comment: This belongs on puzzling.se

Comment: I agree with Ross Millikan. Please visit [the puzzle site](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thank you, as I was unaware of that site